# How to save solution to another place after building project from solution explorer in VS2012?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am creating an website using html in visual studio 2012. So i create new 
  website by select Add->new-->website-->Select-->Asp.net Empty website-->Then my
  own location i saved. So then i add two class libraries to the solution

For BAL Folder One Class library template. And DAL for another class library
  tempate.

So now solution contains 3 projects. When i rebuild my solution Re Build All:
  3 successeded message came in my vs.

The problem after closing my application the main solution this is saved 
  under c:/users/doucments...../with my website name.

So now i want to get this main solution in my own folder only Ex: E:/website.
  In this folder how can i get the main solution to my own folder?

Note : when i create my project web location what i selected in my dropdown is
  "FileSystem" Then i checked in my iis webserver in Default Web Sites. My
   web site is not there?why it is not there in iis?

Comment: Solution is just list of projects. You can put it wherever you want. It may be  easier to have solution+projects in the same folder to simplify GIT repository structure (or whatever source control you use), but it is strictly personal choice.

Comment: Yes i tried to save this solution from my solution explorer like this. Right click on my solution-->Open Folder in my file explorer-->then i copy the packages and solution file -->and paste into my own folder. Then when i open my own solution it open well but when i run the website and view in my browser 403 forbidden error came.instead of web page why?

Comment: Error Is: The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory. But the solution what visual studio created, if i open that solution my project is working fine. but my copied solution is not fine.the above error is came. thanks

Comment: I think your problem is not about moving the solution (*.sln) file but the associated project files. You may want to clarify.